# Cannot read property 'href' of undefined when clicking inactive link a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined
when I click the link a second time. Any thoughts why? It happens on line: var x = $(e.target).atributes.href.value;
And of the course the subsequent redirect doesnt work. Help much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).tap(function (e) {
        $('.pq').css("background-color", "white");

         if ($(e.target).hasClass("tappedonce")) {
        alert("tappedtwice");
                var x = $(e.target).attributes.href.value;
                alert(x);
                window.location.href = x;
            }
            else {
                $(e.target).addClass("tappedonce");
                alert("tappedonce");
            }


      //  if ($(e.target).hasClass("pq")) {
        //        $(e.target).css("background-color", "red");
          //  }
    });


 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.pq').addClass("not-active");
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>



<a href="https://www.sit.com" class="pq">
paragraph1
</a>
<a href="https://www.sit2.com" class="pq">
paragraph2
</a>
<a href="https://www.sit3.com" class="pq">
paragraph3
</a>







</body>
</html>


<style>
    .not-active {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: `$(e.target).atributes.href.value` - `$(e.target)` is a jquery object, not an html node; it doesn't have an "attributes" property (which is what the error is telling you).  You can do either `$(e.target).get(0).atributes.href.value` if you must stick with javascript or `$(e.target).attr("href")` for jquery.

Comment: I'm not getting an error with my jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use:

```
$(e.target).atributes.href.value
```

the `$(e.target)` is a jquery object, not an html node; it doesn't have an "attributes" property (this is what the error is telling you).

You can do convert the jquery object back to an html node via `.get(0)` :

```
var x = $(e.target).get(0).atributes.href.value
```

or just use the original e.target:

```
var x = e.target.atributes.href.value
```

or, to use jquery:

```
var x = $(e.target).attr("href")
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(e.target)` is a jQuery object, you can get the href value via the attr method

```
$(e.target).attr("href")
```

if you want to use `attributes` you'll have to access the underlying dom node, which happens to be `e.target`

```
e.target.attributes.href.value
```